# react-toolbox 2.0-beta.6 themeprovider not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, postcss

i've been trying to override the `color-primary` and `color-accent` vars in [react-toolbox](https://github.com/react-toolbox/react-toolbox) using [react-toolbox-themr](https://github.com/react-toolbox/react-toolbox-themr) but i've been unsuccessful.  i've put together a simple git repo to demonstrate.

here's my `react-toolbox-themr.config.json`

```
{
  "customProperties": {
    "color-primary": "rgb(219,0,0)",
    "color-primary-dark": "rgb(203,0,0)",
    "color-accent": "rgb(64,153,255)",
    "color-accent-dark": "rgb(3,155,229)"
  },
  "output": "src/client/stylesheets/react-toolbox"
}
```

the files build fine, `console.log` and the react devtools shows me that things are being imported correctly... but my app is not getting the theme.

i've tried to keep my theme customization simple and close to the example on the themr site, but i'm coming up with unstyled components.  any help is appreciated.

[here is my repo](https://github.com/rkstar/react-toolbox-dashboard)

Answer (score 0):

i finally figured it out and it was (not really surprised...) a webpack config issue.

here is the commit that made the difference: https://github.com/rkstar/react-toolbox-dashboard/commit/cfcfbd72ce666b1724622fe015b3818fc55c688c?diff=split#diff-1e71174b321bf83364a4a4509f482f9c

what it came down to was that i was using this config (partial) to deal with css files:

```
{
       test: /\.css$/,
       include: [/node_modules/, dir.src],
       use: [{
         loader: 'style-loader'
       },{
         loader: 'css-loader',
         options: {
            modules: true,
            sourceMap: true,
            importLoaders: 1,
            localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
          }
...
}
```

the `'[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'` part was obfuscating my defined class names to include `[name]` of the file (ie. theme[.css]) and adding a 5-char hash to the end of the class names.

what this meant was react-toolbox components are trying to use the class name `rt-appBar-whatever` but my class names (after loaded via webpack loader) were being named `theme__rt-appBar-whatever__99Kiw` <-- obviously this was not working.

i changed the config to use `[local]` exclusively and everything is working as expected!

i hope this will help someone else who may stumble across this issue in the future.